# xunit tests have unexpectedly stopped working in visual studio 2019 .netcore 5

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, xunit

My unit tests have been working fine, ive just finished some additional development and now the tests dont work at all.  They arent failing becuase of changes Ive made, they've simply stopped working.  Im using visual studio 2019 and version 2.4.1 of xunit. I cant even debug them, program execution just stops.  I get this error message

"unexpected error detected. check the tests output pane for details"

and this in the output pane

"The program '[10760] testhost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)."

not helpful at all !

Why would they suddenly stop working, has anyone else experienced this issue ?  Is there a fix ?
(I have no idea why its even happening, there is no infomation to go on)

Comment: This might come as a shock but have you tried turning if off and on again?

Comment: made no difference